# Rubberduck VBA: Commit Failed

Tags: git, ms-access, vbe, rubberduck

I added the files to commit, and clicked in Commit->Go, but I get the following error:

> Commit Failed: Configuration value 'user.name' is missing or invalid[image]

Is something I did wrong? Do I need to create a config file to add the user name?

Thanks

Comment: Is the user name set up in the [Settings] tab?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes it is. And I clicked Update Button before hitting commit

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43269670/1188513